# geom_bar, change distance between columns based on variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have the following bar plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

df<- data.frame(type = c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c","d","d","d","e","e","e"), 
         percentage = c(0.3,0.3,0.4,0.2,0.1,0.7,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.8,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.05,0.65),
         size = c(4,4,4,1,1,1,0.5,0.5,0.5,1,1,1,1,1,1),
         class = as.factor(c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)))

ggplot(df, aes(x=type, y=percentage, width=size/3)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = class), stat="identity") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust=0.3, size=10.)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(name="type") +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Percentage",labels=scales::percent) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "")
```

[image]

The columns (or x-tick marks) are spaced equally.

I would like to find a way to space the columns not equally, trying to reduce white space between the columns which are narrower than others

Comment: Discrete scales are by definition spaced one unit apart. You'll probably have to define your own continious x scale, and adjust the breaks and labels.

Comment: Thank you @Axeman, it works as I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank to @Axeman 2 answers, here is a great solution for the question which allows equally white spaces between columns:

```
library(ggplot2)

df<- data.frame(type = c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c","d","d","d","e","e","e"), 
         percentage = c(0.3,0.3,0.4,0.2,0.1,0.7,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.8,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.05,0.65),
         size = c(4,4,4,1,1,1,0.5,0.5,0.5,1,1,1,1,1,1),
         class = as.factor(c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)))

df$summ <- c(0,0,0, na.omit(0.5 * df$size + 0.5 * dplyr::lag(df$size, n=3))) + 
           max(df$size)/5.0
df$summ <- ave(df$summ,df$class,FUN=cumsum)

ggplot(df, aes(x=summ, y=percentage, width=size)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = class), stat="identity") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust=0.3, size=10.)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(name="type", breaks=unique(df$summ), labels=c("a","b","c","d","e")) +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Percentage",labels=scales::percent) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "")
```

[image: Solution]

Comment: You can make this more exact if you want. E.g.: the breaks can be `c(0, cumsum(na.omit(0.5 * sizes + 0.5 * dplyr::lag(sizes))) + cumsum(rep(0.2, 4)))`, where sizes here are `c(4, 1, 0.5, 1, 1)`, and `0.2` is the size of the white space.

Comment: Thank you again Axeman, i am going to add this idea for a better solution